# Finding Theta notation for $E[X]$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

The problem is explained as such:

A plant grows everyday by the following:

At day $0$, $h = 0$ (Height)

At the beginning of every day, if $h=i$, than it will grow to $h=i+1$ with probability $P=\frac {1}{i+1}$.

Else, it stays the same height.

We will notate $X$ for the number of days it took the plant to reach $h=n$, and we're asked to find a big theta notation for $E[X]$

I've defined $X_i$~$Geo(\frac {1}{i})$ such that $X_i$ is the number of days it took to reach from height $i-1$ to height $i$

$E[X]=E[X_1+X_2+ \ldots +X_n]=E[X_1]+ \ldots +E[X_n]$

Because a geometric RV with probability $p$ has the expected value of $\frac {1}{p}$,than:

$E[X_1]+ \ldots +E[X_n]=\frac {1}{\frac {1}{1}}+\frac {1}{\frac {1}{2}}+ \ldots + \frac {1}{\frac {1}{n}}=1+2+ \ldots +n=n^2$ and therefore, $E[X]=\Theta (n^2)$

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to find out weather my solution is correct or atleast going in the right direction, since I have no way to confirm the correctness of my solution.